# Java Web Start support in Java 9 and beyond

Tags: java, java-web-start, java-9

I'm confused about the status of Java Web Start.
On Oracle's [Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) we can read this:

> **Support of Deployment Technology**
>
> The web deployment technology, consisting of the Java Plugin and Web Start technologies, has a shorter support lifecycle. For major releases through Java SE 8, Oracle provides five (5) years of Premier Support for these technologies. Extended Support is not available for the deployment stack, and will not be available for support beyond Java SE 9. See the Oracle Lifetime Support Policy for details.
>
> Deployment Technology for Java SE 6 and Java SE 7 may be removed at any time after Jun 2017.  *Although the deployment stack may be included in Java SE 9 or later releases, Java SE 8 is the recommended and only supported version of the deployment stack*.

Now, we have known for quite some time that applets and the Java Plugin were to be removed in a future version of Java, but I had never read about Java Web Start being a candidate for removal.

In Oracle's [Java Platform, Standard Edition Deployment Guide#Getting Started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/getting-started.htm#JSDPG101) (a Java 9 documentation page), Java Web Start is advertised as an alternative to the deprecated applet technology:

> Although available and supported in JDK 9, the Applet API and the Java Plug-in are marked as deprecated in preparation for removal in a future release. Alternatives for applets and embedded JavaFX applications include Java Web Start and self-contained applications.

Am I worrying for nothing or I have missed an announcement about the deprecation of Java Web Start?

Comment: If my understanding is correct : Java Web Start will no longer support  deployement of Java Applications in version 6 and 7. The java plugin (for browser) and the applets will be removed, but the Java Web Start launcher will continue to be maintained

Comment: Not very sure what's the area of concern here since this seems to be addressing a very broad category as of now. Off-topic?

Comment: @nullpointer I wasn't sure this belonged in SO honestly, but didn't know which sub-site from StackExchange it would best fit. The area of concern is in the question at the end: has there been an official communication about Java Web Start being discontinued, or is it just the Java Plug-in?

Comment: I would ideally suggest (1) moving this to a mailing list. (2) narrowing down the scope primarily to any of your application (3) expecting the authors to come up with a relevant source of truth.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html

> Java Deployment Technologies are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
>
> Java Applet and WebStart functionality, including the Applet API, The Java plug-in, the Java Applet Viewer, **JNLP and Java Web Start including the javaws tool** are all deprecated in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future release.

There is a related discussion on the OpenJDK discuss list here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2017-November/004586.html

> Oracle will not include Java Web Start in Java SE 11 (18.9 LTS) and later.

Source: [Java Client Roadmap Update 2018-03-05 (Oracle)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)

Comment: I had made an attempt to get an answer from Oracle's community forums, without success. Sad news as the proposed alternative (jlink) doesn't seem to offer an equivalent set of features. Thanks a lot for the OpenJDK list.

Comment: Oracle is forgetting that the success of Java was thanks to "Write once, Run Everywhere"
Now, it seems, it is more like "Re-Write every Year, or Run Anywhere (Else)"

Comment: I'm really shocked by this news... Just discovered today that a deprecation warning is shown by Java 10 when starting an application with Java Web Start...

Answer (score 8):

This applies to [Premier, Extended and Sustaining Support](https://www.oracle.com/support/lifetime-support/index.html). Just from the quoted text:

- only Premier Support covers the Deployment Technology;
- the Deployment Technology could be removed in future Java SE 6 and 7 releases;
- as the applet API and plug-in are deprecated, the Deployment Technology could be removed in a future major release;
- Java 9 Premier Support only lasts until March 2018.

Consequently, Java 8 is the only release that will include the full Deployment Technology with mid-term Premier Support (March 2022).

Note that it does not mean Java Web Start will disappear but removing the Applet API and the plug-in means breaking apart the Deployment Technology.

Answer (score 6):

One solution might be the WebStart replacement that Karakun is currently working on: https://openwebstart.com

Currently it is not clear when and how this will come since it is based on a kind of crowd-founding but since everyone can get involved (even with low cost) this is a very good possibility.

Since this is a duplicate of [Applet/JNLP on Java 11 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981336/applet-jnlp-on-java-11-migration/52381741#52381741) I just copied my answer

Comment: Any reason for not using IcedTea-Web?

Comment: OpenWebStart uses IcedTea-Web. It has an installer based on install4j and they created their version of the Java Control Panel, which turned out to be part of Oracle Java Web Start as well and not of the JRE. Plus unattended installation. Great job!

Answer (score 3):

I saw this on an [Oracle Blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/extension-of-oracle-java-se-8-public-updates-and-java-web-start-support?elq_mid=102312&sh=0912080824121522142613293528281507&cmid=WWMK170418P00047)

> Tuesday, January 30, 2018
>
> **Extension of Oracle Java SE 8 Public Updates and Java Web Start
>   support By: Donald Smith | Sr. Director of Product Management**
>
> Oracle has updated the Java SE Support Roadmap.  A more detailed white
>   paper will follow shortly, but here are the key changes made:
>
> - The public availability of Java SE 8 updates from Oracle has been extended to at least January 2019.  Moreover, Oracle will continue to
>     provide consumers with updates for personal (non-corporate) use of
>     Java SE 8 through at least the end of 2020.
> - Oracle will continue to support Java SE 8 Web Start applications for public and personal (non-corporate) use to the same dates noted
>     above.
> - Oracle will continue to commercially support Java Web Start on Java SE 8 for commercial use, or when used in conjunction with Oracle
>     products that have a Web Start dependency, through at least March,
>     2025.
> - As announced in 2015, Applets will continue to be supported in Java SE 8 until at least March, 2019, pending continued support by browser
>     vendors.

Answer (score 0):

I started using IcedTea Web. It seams to work fine on Ubuntu.