# jnlp and javawebstart technologies depracated in jdk9 - alternatives?

Tags: java, web, applet

I just inherited project that consists of a Java applet and some server communications, and with it found out that this technology is no longer supported by oracle.
My first thought was to wrap it in a JNLP and javawebstart but since oracle also marked this as deprecated in jdk9 i cannot use it as i need a long term support solution.
I want to try avoiding a complete re-write of the applet.
Does anybody have any ideas on this? Are there other alternatives on the market? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Web Start support in Java 9 and beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904795/java-web-start-support-in-java-9-and-beyond)

Comment: *"Are there other alternatives on the market?"* Yes. JS & HTML. Together they can provide the functionality of 90% of applets ever written. Throw in the HTML 5 `canvas` element & that becomes 95% (or beyond). What does this applet do?

Comment: Thank you, but by alternatives i'm reffering to something to launch the applet, something along the lines of JNLP, but supported by modern browsers.  As i said i would avoid re-writing the app.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out https://github.com/update4j/update4j which natively supports Java 9.

Also allows distibuting files base on operating system. And you can sign files to prevent Man In The Middle attacks. And much more.